# How to use double ampersand or any other better alternative in c?

Tags: c

I am new to C. I used pointer but It does not work in the case when there is already an ampersand as two ampersands cannot be put. I made a strcpy_s function to make it easy to prevent L buffer is too small.

```
void strcpy_s_1(char** dest_str, char* str) {
    int len = strlen(str);
    *dest_str = (char*)malloc(len + 1);
    strcpy_s(*dest_str, len + 1, str);
}
```

but it causes issue in this function:

```
char* replaceWord(const char* s, const char* oldW,
    const char* newW)
{
    char* result;
    int i, cnt = 0;
    int newWlen = strlen(newW);
    int oldWlen = strlen(oldW);

    // Counting the number of times old word
    // occur in the string
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (strstr(&s[i], oldW) == &s[i]) {
            cnt++;

            // Jumping to index after the old word.
            i += oldWlen - 1;
        }
    }

    // Making new string of enough length
    result = (char*)malloc(i + cnt * (newWlen - oldWlen) + 1);

    i = 0;
    while (*s) {
        // compare the substring with the result
        if (strstr(s, oldW) == s) {
            strcpy_s_1(&&result[i], newW);
            i += newWlen;
            s += oldWlen;
        }
        else
            result[i++] = *s++;
    }
    result[i] = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

The original line of command was

```
strcpy_s(&result[i], sizeof(&result[i]), newW);
```

Comment: Double ampersand? You mean the logical and operator?

Comment: @Shawn He means the address of operator.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I was trying to make a function that assigns a value to string without returning any value. But that could not work when there is already a "&" in a command as double "&" changes the meaning.

Comment: @Himanshu What is the word in your case? Is it a sequence of characters separated by spaces?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I am referring to line "strcpy_s_1(&&result[i], newW);" in second function.

Comment: @Himanshu I asked what is the word. As for your code then it does not make a sense. You can not reallocate a part of an array as you are trying to do strcpy_s_1(&&result[i], newW);

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I understand that I cannot reallocate, that is why I searched a lot but did not found any alternative. So I thought to ask here.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I was trying to assign a value to string without using "return" from a function.

Comment: Edit the question and show example **input** AND **desired output** that would use your function... "How do I get from _this_ to _this_?" That kind of example... This code is very difficult to make sense of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in C && is not a valid operator.

the & operator returns the value address of the variable.

Look at this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a = 1;
  int * p;
  int **q;

  p = &a;
  q = &p;

  printf(" &a %p, &p %p, &q %p \n", &a, &p, &q);
  printf(" a %d , p %p, q %p", a, p, q);
  return 0;
}
```

that shows:

```
&a 0x7ffcbe4cbba4, &p 0x7ffcbe4cbba8, &q 0x7ffcbe4cbbb0 
a 1 , p 0x7ffcbe4cbba4, q 0x7ffcbe4cbba8
```

As you can see the value of q is the same as &p, which means that the address of p is stored in q. But, if I try to do this:

```
printf(" &&q %p", &(&q));
```

it shows me this error:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:23:23: error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
23 |     printf(" &&q %p", &(&q));
   |                       ^
```

Because the "&" operator could be used just once, it return the value address, and in C there is no sense to "value address of the value address"

Hope this can help to understand the problem :)